# Limite de perguntas, isso é correto?

Tags: suporte, perguntas

Publiquei muitas perguntas aqui no site e me apareceu a seguinte mensagem:

<kbd>[image: Você atingiu seu limite de perguntas]</kbd>

Eu tive que criar uma nova conta aqui no site, isso é algum tipo de bug, não?

Comment: Criar novas contas só vai piorar sua situação.

Comment: Bom ver que considerou o meta como suporte, parece que agora está empenhado em usar a ferramenta corretamente, fico feliz por isso :).

Comment: Relacionado: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2230/tradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-da-mensagem-de-bloqueio-tempor%C3%A1rio

Comment: Lamborguinhi, parece que você atingiu o limite ***antes*** de ele ter sido oficialmente anunciado ([*Rolling question rate limits are now network-wide*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243460/185667)), e isso merece um parabéns :P  . . . . . A ironia aqui é grande demais, não posso deixar de notar a metáfora do carro que foi usada no Metão e o nick/avatar do nosso primeiro usuário a ter o limite de velocidade imposto aqui no SOpt..!

Comment: @brasofilo Gostei da sua observação bem humorada, Entendi antes de fazer qualquer pergunta irei tentar algum tipo de debug

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Após fazer várias questões que não foram bem recebidas pela comunidade, o sistema faz uma estatistica baseado em criterios como  balanço de downvotes/updates que a pergunta recebeu, questões sem accpet, publicações excluidas ou fechadas etc.

Das 15 questões publicadas que você tem, 8 delas tem votos negativos, em outras algumas pessoas reclamando da identação do código.

A ideia é você caprichar na hora de elaborar questões, o primeiro passo é fazer um debug tentar isolar uma parte do código feito isso se possível crie um exemplo menor(menos complexo) onde o erro seja reproduzível.

Na questão seja objetivo, descreva com detalhes o problema, o que deveria ser feito, se o que ocorre é um erro ou um resultado não esperado, adicione a parte relevante do código fonte identada e formatada ou até mesmo uma imagem(no caso de html/css quebrado), versões dos softwares, mensagens ou códigos de erros e quais as tentativas de resolver o problema que tentou e falhou. Evite explicar ou resumir o problema com termos ruins como 'não funciona', 'não pegou/foi/deu' ou 'deu erro/pau/creps'.

Antes de publicar a questão faça um intervalo de 10 a 15 minutos depois disso leia-a novamente veja se está clara e se não esqueceu de algo. Pensar em como responder a sua própria questão pode eliminar algumas falhas de compreensão e também pode tornar sua pergunta mais fácil de responder.

Comment: Outra dica: ler com atenção e carinho os comentários deixados por usuários experientes. Eu já cansei de dar dicas pro Aventador sobre como melhorar a qualidade, mas obviamente fui ignorado.

Comment: @brasofilo tento melhorar mais sou péssimo em perguntar

Comment: A receita não é complicada, @Lamborghini: título explicativo + explicação do problema + o que pesquisou + erros obtidos + resultado esperado + corretor ortográfico. Sorte aê :)

Comment: Mais uma coisa: são 16 perguntas excluídas, mais da metade do total. Isso provavelmente é levado em conta pelo algoritmo que impôs esse limite à conta.

Comment: @LamborghiniAventador Sugiro que você revise as excluídas, edite e desfaça a exclusão do que for possível. Não recupere as duplicadas, mas tente melhorar bem o que achar que pode ser salvo.

Comment: @bfavaretto, não cabe tradução à mensagem que ele recebeu?

Comment: Não esquecer [desse link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited) da central de ajuda também.

Comment: @PapaCharlie Sem dúvida cabe. Não falei disso porque é a primeira coisa que o Gabe vai perceber quando vir o screenshot :) E ele é quem tem a ferramenta de tradução. Aliás, alguém se dispõe a traduzir e postar no meta como `novo-recurso`?

Comment: @perdeu Acho que isto deveria ser um comentário enlatado para os novatos no site...

Comment: Eu fazia muita pergunta sem nexo no início, e era tudo falta de atenção. Hoje em dia eu leio três vezes antes de enviar a pergunta e sempre funciona. É sempre bom ver o outro lado.

Comment: Perguntar é fácil, difícil é programar.

Comment: @bigown, de vez em quando também solto essa: é **muito mais fácil** aprender a usar o Stack do que programar. Não entendo porque tanta gente bate cabeça quando era só sentar e ler o diacho do manual do site em 45 minutos. E uns outros 45 de pesquisa no Meta. E pronto, só alegria.

Comment: @bfavaretto, traduzi o texto que estava no screenshot, postar a tradução como uma pergunta?

Comment: @perdeu Sim sim sim!