# O que fazer com perguntas que não são mais úteis?

Tags: debate, suporte, pergunta-específica

Há algum tempo atrás fiz a seguinte [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38422/exportar-arquivos-do-sqlite-para-csv), porém, com o avanço do projeto, decidimos não implementar essa parte. Por isso não pesquisei sobre o assunto, sendo assim não posso postar uma resposta válida. Além disso ninguém respondeu, ou seja, não queria deixar ela poluindo sem resposta, mas não sei se o certo era excluir, pelo caso que [aconteceu com o Aventador](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2221/limite-de-perguntas-isso-%C3%A9-corr%C3%A9to).
Como procedo?

Comment: acho que a pergunta está boa e deveria ficar no site. Acho que não tem problema algum. Se a quiseres excluir ai já é a tua consideração. O não ter resposta não torna a pergunta "Não útil" poderá ser útil para alguém saber que não tem resposta e escusa perguntar de novo.

Comment: Não sei se sou daltônico, mas demorei pra achar o link da pergunta, hehehe. Chances de mudar o estilo do link? :)

Comment: @Earendul, não, o esquema de cores aqui pros links tem um contraste beeeem duvidoso... eu também quase reclamei "cadê o link" ao ler da primeira vez.

Comment: Esse contraste do link já foi até discutido no meta, cheguei a dizer que precisa de uma melhora significativa.

Answer (score 11):

Antes de mais nada, o caso do Aventador é bem extremo, 16 perguntas deletadas e metade das existentes com pontuação negativa. Além disso, acredito que usuários recentes e/ou de baixa reputação são mais "vigiados" que os já estabelecidos e que em teoria já conhecem bem o sistema.

Acho que no seu caso específico, fica a seu critério excluir aquela pergunta ou não. Eu pesaria o seguinte:

- acha que ela pode ser útil para outra pessoa?
- caso afirmativo, pode simplificar para torná-la mais genérica e útil?
- se achar que pode ser útil no futuro para outras pessoas, deixa estar e que o sistema decida por você se deletar ou não.

A deleção automática vai disparar nos casos de:
<sup><sub>(fontes: [Como uma pergunta pode ser excluída e efetivamente removida do site?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1558/201) & [*How does deleting work?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/185667))</sub></sup>

- depois de 30 dias: pergunta sem resposta e com pontuação negativa.
- depois de 365 dias: pergunta sem resposta, pontuação zero, menos de 1.5 visualizações por dia e menos de dois comentários.

PS: eu acho bem legal ao aprender uma nova tecnologia, sair procurando perguntas sem resposta para poder estudar um problema e aprender através disso.

Comment: E digo "em teoria" porque já vi muito usuário lá no SO com 10k+ que ignora completamente certos aspectos do sistema.

Comment: Aqui também :D nas devidas proporções

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se tenho a mesma idéia de "Pergunta não útil" que você.

Mas acredito que perguntas que são fora do escopo ou que não atendem os requisitos para pertencer ao site deveriam ser excluídas, [exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40026/).

1. Essa pergunta não tem nada a ver com programação.
2. Foi fechada e não há nenhuma possibilidade dela ser reaberta.
3. Deixa o site mais poluído pois não é um conteúdo relevante.

E perguntas de baixa qualidade (que foram fechadas e não houve um esforço do autor de melhorar), depois de um determinado período (*ex:* 3 meses) também deveriam ser excluídas! Pelo mesmos motivos citados.

Talvez alguém fale que fechar perguntas e deixar elas no site serve como "exemplo" assim se a pessoa teve a percepção que uma pergunta no mesmo estilo foi fechada ela não irá perguntar novamente.

Comment: então o que eu quis dizer é não útil por não ter resposta, ou seja se alguém respondesse eu iria aprender e tal mas ainda não sei o que fazer. você viu a pergunta?

Comment: My bad, entendi! Aconteceu algo parecido comigo, eu sinalizei e pedi pro moderador excluir.

Comment: @Laerte o exemplo que você deu será removido pelo sistema em algum momento, não se preocupe. As demais depende um pouco. Tem muita pergunta de baixíssima qualidade que tem votos positivos. Isto ocorre porque alguns usuários não tem muito senso crítico e alguns até gostam de sair votando em qualquer coisa, gostam de "ajudar" o coitado do AP que não conseguiu formular um pergunta decente (isso, em geral, não ajuda o AP e prejudica a comunidade). Nestes casos o uso do negativo (consciente) é ainda mais importante para que o *garbage collector* da SE possa agir com tranquilidade.